# Basic jQuery: click a button to slide text panel off screen, click another button to slide it back on screen

Tags: jquery, animation, button, fadein, fadeout

I'm maintaining a website that has full screen background photos, and a text panel on top of the photos.

Here's the functionality I want to add:

Clicking "Hide text" button makes the text panel animate left off-screen, so that the visitors can see the whole background photo. The "Hide text" button, after being clicked, should fade out, and another button, "Show text" fades in in a different place. When "Show text" button is clicked, the text panel should animate from off-screen left back to its proper place. Simultaneously, "Show text" button should fades out, and "Hide text" button should fade in.

To rephrase it:

when #hideText is clicked,

aimate #mainPanel left off-screen, fade out #hideText, fade in #showText.

when #showText is clicked,

animate #mainPanel from its current position left off-screen to its proper place onscreen, fade out #showText, fade in #hideText

Could someone please show me how to do this with jQuery? I would be very grateful for actual code.

Comment: Well, you're asking for a lot of things - basically doing the whole stuff actually. There are tons of tutorials you can find on google to start with. We can help you resolve problems but obvously cannot do the work for you. Check these: [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) - [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) - [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dXSPa/

```
$('#hideText').click(function(){
    $('#mainPanel').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $('#showText').fadeIn();
});
$('#showText').click(function(){
    $('#mainPanel').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $('#hideText').fadeIn();
});
​
```

and html (just for an example)

```
<div id='mainPanel' 
      style='position:absolute; left: 0px; top: 50px; 
            border: 1px solid black; white-space: nowrap'>Main Panel</div>
<input type='button' id='hideText' value='Hide Text'
       style='position:absolute;left:0px'>
<input type='button' id='showText' value='Show Text' 
       style='display:none; position:absolute;right:0px;'>
```

if you do not like the width effect it can be easily modified for the slide out of the left side of screen, like this http://jsfiddle.net/3FwWV/

ps: for the button on the right - click on the button, not on the jsfiddle's span with word 'Result'

Comment: Cheery – thank you so much, this is GREAT! – except what I see in jsfiddle seems to be working in reverse: when "Hide text" button is clicked, a text panel appears, and "Show text" fades in. Clicking on "Show text" has no result... May I please ask you to update your answer to make it work? I would be truly grateful.

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov  `Clicking on "Show text" has no result..` it works, there is a half-transparent div from the jsfiddle with word 'Result' on it. It is over the button, click on the button, not on the div.

Comment: I see now! BUT – "Hide text" button doesn't hide the text, it SHOWS it. And vice versa. How do I reverse that? :-)

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov It is not just a figure of speech - I'm in NY, too. So, if you any further questions about jQuery (js in general and other stuff), feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks! How can we get in touch outside of this website?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov I sent email to your address listed in whois information of your domain.

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/

Check the slide effect and implementation here.

Comment: Thank you LinuxEasy – the demo you showed me is interesting, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I guess I explained it in words in a clumsy way. I've just edited the question a bit, could you take a look?

Comment: You can check the source which is provided at the given link. It shows how its implemented. So the code you want to be put is already there, and other options can be checked too by checking other animations. And the effect shown on the link works on a click of button only.